# Can app users edit app files?

Tags: ios, objective-c

A new-ish developer here! I had a search around the web for an answer but couldn't find one.

Can a user somehow view and maybe edit app files such as the ViewController or AppDelegate?
I'm not just talking about the average user, but a tech savvy dude. If it can be edited, what files can't be viewed and/or edited?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you talking about source code files? Source code files never end up on devices unless something has gone horribly wrong.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know. Thanks. If you put that as an answer I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code files never end up on iOS devices unless something has gone horribly wrong. The source code is compiled into executables and frameworks, and it is those compiled files (along with resources existing outside of the compiled files) that are installed.

Answer (score 1):

well. source code never makes it to the user. it is COMPILED

BUT

resources can be edited

BUT

that destroys code-signing and renders the app unusable on a non-jailbroken phone

Answer (score 1):

No, they cannot. Not source code files, since they never ends up in the compiled app. (Unless you include them as resources, but that would be a very strange thing to do.)

However, a user with a jailbroken device *can* edit and access your `.nib`, `.strings`, `.plist` files, etc. I.e. everything you add to the bundle resources. To see what this is, go to 
`Project -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources`in Xcode.